# How to find similar values from list but not exact?

Tags: python, regex, list, bigdata

I have more than 500k records of city names, But data is not correctly typed for example word `AHMADNAGAR` is typed in ways below,

```
 1. AEHMADNAGAR
 2. AHEMADNAGR
 3. AHMAD NAGAR
 4. AHMADNAGGAR
```

This is an example of only one city, I have to scan more than 500k records & want to **find similar words but not exactly similar.**

I created the `.txt` file and I'm sharing the link, where I included 17K Cities, please see file [Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaustubhk24/Indian-Banks-Data/main/DATA/RAW/districts.txt)

What I tried?

```
from difflib import get_close_matches
        
def closeMatches(patterns, word):
    print(get_close_matches(word, patterns))

    
citylist=['AHMADNAGAR','XYZ','AEHMADNAGAR','AHEMADNAGR','AHMADNAGAR','AHMADNAGGAR','ABC','test','test2']
     for city in citylist:  
         closeMatches(patterns, city)
```

Expected output: (as we're passing `city` runtime it should print similar values but not exactly similar, even I already removed similar values, We don't have any duplicates)

```
example output of one city ( we have 500K cities, please check file, I included some of them there )

    AHMADNAGAR
    AEHMADNAGAR
    AHEMADNAGR
    AHMADNAGAR
    AHMADNAGGAR
```

The problem here is, can not pass `city` here to create `pattern` manually & another thing is it is not showing all variations.

I learned from my friend that we can use `regex`, but how? Is there any way to create `regex runtime` and match it with all records

Just want to get the list of similar cities

Comment: I think `get_close_matches` is what you want to use, but you're using it backwards.  Could you expand your code a bit to include `citylist` and the desired output?

Comment: I just updated with desired output can you please check?

Comment: It looks like in your example you only need to match against a single city (AHMADNAGAR), which makes this just a single simple call to `get_close_matches`.

Comment: Note: What I would expect from your description is that you have two lists -- a list of (correctly-spelled) city names, and a list of (maybe incorrectly-spelled) user inputs.  If that is indeed the problem you're trying to solve, please update your example to show both lists and the expected output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for you to implement your own loop or wrap `get_close_matches` in another function.  Just provide the name of the city that you want to match against (`'AHMADNAGAR'`) and the list of possible matches to the `get_close_matches` function.  It defaults to 3, so specify a higher `n` if you want more.

```
>>> from difflib import get_close_matches
>>> citylist=['AHMADNAGAR','XYZ','AEHMADNAGAR','AHEMADNAGR','AHMADNAGAR','AHMADNAGGAR','ABC','test','test2']
>>> get_close_matches('AHMADNAGAR', citylist, n=len(citylist))
['AHMADNAGAR', 'AHMADNAGAR', 'AHMADNAGGAR', 'AEHMADNAGAR', 'AHEMADNAGR']
```

Note that the result is sorted by similarity, so the exact match is first, followed by the closest match, etc.

Documentation for `difflib` is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html

Comment: Hello, I just shared a link in question to file which contains 17K cities from my records, AHMADNAGAR is only one example, I want to iterate through each city and find similar to that, but not exact

Comment: Please update your code to be a minimally reproducible example with a list of cities, a list of sample inputs, and the expected output based on those inputs.  The example you provided does not really match the thing you're trying to build since all of the inputs correspond to the same city.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd argument for `get_close_matches()` is a list, if you're just trying to get the close matches, you could run:

```
from difflib import get_close_matches
    
city_list = ['AHMADNAGAR','AEHMADNAGAR','AHEMADNAGR','AHMAD NAGAR', 'AHMADNAGGAR','test','test2']

close_matches = get_close_matches('AHMADNAGAR', city_list)
for close_match in close_matches:
    print(close_match)
```

Comment: I will try to do this, meanwhile, I updated some code in question, if you could please check , Thanks in advance

Comment: I just checked it's not printing these values  `AEHMADNAGAR`, `AHEMADNAGR`

Comment: @KaustubhKulkarni I'm looking into it. Also you are missing an apostrophe before the comma on the 5th item

Comment: Ok, I fixed the comma, also here in case we're just passing a single city for example but in reality we need to send multiple cities at a time, So I iterated through the city list, but it's showing unexpected output ``` for d in city_list:
    close_matches = get_close_matches(d, city_list)
for close_match in close_matches:
    print(close_match)```

Comment: @KaustubhKulkarni please update your question to include your intended input for multiple cities as well. I guess I don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Hello, I just shared a link in question to file which contains 17K cities from my records, AHMADNAGAR is only one example, I want to iterate through each city and find similar to that, but not exact

Comment: [`get_close_matches`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) have other optional arguments you can play with to get more matches, you in this example you can increase the value of `n` to get results: `get_close_matches('AHMADNAGAR', city_list, n=10)` gives `['AHMADNAGAR', 'AHMADNAGGAR', 'AHMAD NAGAR', 'AEHMADNAGAR', 'AHEMADNAGR']`